# Ruby On Rails + PostgreSQL: If not matching data found, return the row as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, case, rails-activerecord

I have these two models:

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :model_b
  has_one :model_b
end

class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_a
end
```

Data in DB tables:

```
model_a
id | ...
1  | ...
2  | ...
3  | ...

model_b
id | model_a_id | value_a | value_b
1  | 1          | abc     | def
2  | 2          | ghi     | jkl
```

For every record in the the `model_a`, I want to get a record from table `model_b` - I can get it like this.

```
ModelA.joins('LEFT JOIN model_b ON model_b.model_a_id = model_a.id')
```

This query would return me the rows with ID `1` and `2` from the table `model_a`. However, I would like to get returned also the row with ID `3` from the table `model_a` and for this row, I would want to get returned the associated (in this case, non-existing) row from `model_b` with these values:

```
value_a: NULL
value_b: NULL
```

How do I do that? I tried to play with different `JOINS`, with `CASE IF/ELSE/END`, but I happened to not find the right combination.

As I need to be able to filter/query these data, I believe it would be probably better to solve this on the PSQL level, rather than on Rails.

**EDIT:** `RIGHT JOIN` returns me only the first 2 rows form `model_a`.

**EDIT2:** This is the desired output:

```
modal_a.id | modal_b.value_a | modal_b.value_b
1          | abc             | def
2          | ghi             | jkl
3          | null            | null
```

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a left outer join

```
ModelA.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN model_b ON model_b.model_a_id = model_a.id')
```

It will return all ModelA records even if no modelB record is present.

In pure rails...

```
ModelA.includes(:model_b)
```

To explicitly include the columns that may have nil...

```
records = ModelA.includes(:model_b).select('*, model_b.value_a as model_b_value_a, model_b.value_b as model_b_value_b')
```

This lets you do `records.first.id` to see the `model_a` id, and `records.first.model_b_value_a` etc to see the value from `model_b`

For records without an associated `model_b` record, `records.first.model_b_value_a` will return nil

Comment: Hi @SteveTurczyn, thank you for your answer. I probably didn't get myself clear enough - I added the desired output.

Comment: What are you getting when you try `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ?  It should work...

Comment: Added to the answer.